# Angular: Type-ahead suggestions not shown again after hide on clicking outside

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I'm trying to implement a type-ahead functionality that shows suggestions as you type. Once the user clicks somewhere, the element (`ul`) that displays the suggestions is hidden (setting `style.display` to `none`).

If you take a look at this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qcqjvf) (test data: 1, 12, 123), I'm trying to set `style.display` back to `block`, if suggestions are available and the search textbox is not empty. But it is not setting it back to `block`. If you clear and focus out of the `textbox` and type again, the suggestions are shown.

Have been cracking my head, but couldn't figure out why. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I wild guess: besides setting display to none, reset matchedItems to [] on document click